# How do I show a notification from a python3 application in Ubuntu 18.04 desktop?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome, notification

Whenever an application has some error and needs to show it as a notice, Ubuntu 18.04 would first flash the notice below the clock that is located at the Desktop Top-panel (Notification Popup) and store it in the Notification Area.

How do I similarly show a notice from my python3 application in the same manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `notify-send`.

From `man notify-send`:

> With  notify-send  you  can  send  desktop notifications to the user
>   via a notification daemon from the command line.  These notifications
>   can be used to inform the user about an event or display some form of
>   information without getting in the user's way.

Notifications sent to the user screen will stay up for a few seconds, and will be stored in the notification area under the clock, as you require.

Comment: OP asking about python so ... In python 3 I find it easiest to make os calls with `subprocess.getoutput` : `subprocess.getoutput("notify-send 'Greetings from Sun Bear'")`

Comment: Thanks. I integrated `notify-send` with `subprocess.run()` in python3.6 like so: **1st line** `from subprocess import run`, **2nd line**  `run(['notify-send', 'Greetings from Sun Bear'])`

Comment: If the msg is longer than a certain length, the msg gets truncated. Is there a way to untruncate the msg in the notification?

Comment: I have no idea. However, you could possibly use [this](https://github.com/vlevit/notify-send.sh/blob/master/notify-send.sh) replacement for notify-send and adjust parameters.